# Is it possible to develop HTML5 social game (like poker) without including server(just client side app) in which multiple users are connected?

Tags: html

Basically I want make a social game like poker, in which multiple players gets connected. 
But I don't want server side interaction.

So my idea was to make one person's browser acts like server and other acts as client.

Person A's browser will hold the data( client side DB) and communicate with person B via web sockets or something.

I am not sure if two browsers can some how connected with sockets. Either web sockets(HTML5) or any flash plugin which can help to IP to IP connection. Is it possible somehow?

As of now I am not even sure how users will connect for starting the game. I may need to put server for initial connection.

Answer (score 3):

Currently you cannot do this with web browsers because they cannot act like a server. It will probably be possible in the future though: [Chrome is experimenting with a Socket implementation](http://developer.chrome.com/apps/socket.html) (this is an experimental feature in Canary releases that is disabled by default). [Node.js has already (partially) been ported](http://iceddev.github.com/blog/2012/11/05/node-js-in-chrome/) using chrome.socket.

With Flash, it is possible to create p2p multi player games since version 10, but you still need a central server to setup the initial connections between players. There's a library for it here: http://www.flashrealtime.com/p2p-game-lib/.

Be aware that p2p multi player games make it easier for players to cheat, because the authority lies with one or multiple players, and not with a central server.

Comment: Chrome's Socket API will not be available to regular web pages, just for apps ([What are Packaged Apps?](http://developer.chrome.com/apps/about_apps.html)).

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible for a browser to accept a websocket request so a server is necessary for you to handle such a request. For how to set up a websocket server, I recommend [socket.io](http://socket.io/) that is based on node.js. It's very easy to use and it's only javascript that is a language that web developers get used to.